# Iterative counter on vector of symbols (MATLAB)

Tags: matlab

Imagine my alpha-beta is '0', 'E' (E can be equal to a number i.e: E=0.5) and '1'  I want to have counter as follows:

```
[ 0 0 0 ]
[ 0 0 E ]
[ 0 0 1 ]
[ 0 E 0 ]
[ 0 E E ]
[ 0 E 1 ]  
[ 0 1 0 ]
[ 0 1 E ]
[ 0 1 1 ]
[ E 0 0 ]
[ E 0 E ]
[ E 0 1 ]
[ E E 0 ]
...
```

... And so on till we get to [1 1 1] (In this example it's 3^3 combinations).
At the beginning I tried `combvec()` function but if you need vector with length of 16 symbols it should allocate matrix of 3^16 for 3^16 combinations.. So I got `OUT OF MEMORY` error. That's why I need a counter so each time I could calculate the next vector and use it without trying to get all combinations at once like in `combvec()`. Any idea?

Answer (score 3):

Those are just ternary numbers written with digits `0`,`E`, and `1`.  Look at the Matlab function `dec2base` which translates decimal numbers into strings representing the same number in other bases. Matlab also provides the inverse function `base2dec`.

You'll need to do some string transformation on the result to change `1` to `E` and `2` to `1` but I'll leave that to you.

Answer (score 0):

What you want to do is pretty similar to counting numbers in base 3, but instead of numbers 0,1,2 you use the symbols (0, E, 1). To count in arbitrary base, you could store a number as an array of its digits. Counting means repeatedly adding 1, so lets implement some elementary school style `add_one` function, where you add numbers one column at a time and continue bringing the carry over to the column on the left in case of overflow:

```
function num = add_one(num, base)
% num is an array with numbers 0..base-1, representing the digits of a number
i = length(num); % start in right column
while i > 0
    num(i) = num(i) + 1; % add one
    if num(i) == base % overflow?
        num(i) = 0; % set digit to zero and add one to the column on the left
        i = i - 1;
    else
        break % we are done
    end
end
```

Quick test:

```
>> num = [0, 0, 0];
>> for i=1:10
disp(num)
num = add_one(num, 3);
end
```

Result:

```
     0     0     0
     0     0     1
     0     0     2
     0     1     0
     0     1     1
     0     1     2
     0     2     0
     0     2     1
     0     2     2
     1     0     0
```

exactly like counting in base 3!

Now all we have to do is translate these numbers to your symbols, which can be done with a simple lookup (note that matlab's arrays use 1-based indexing, so we have to add 1):

```
>> num = [0, 0, 0];
>> symbols = {'0', 'E', '1'};
>> for i = 1:3^3
       disp(sprintf('%s ', symbols{num + 1}))
       num = add_one(num, 3);
   end
```

Result:

```
0 0 0 
0 0 E 
0 0 1 
0 E 0 
0 E E 
0 E 1 
0 1 0 
0 1 E 
0 1 1 
E 0 0 
E 0 E 
E 0 1 
E E 0 
 ...
1 E 1 
1 1 0 
1 1 E 
1 1 1
```

Answer (score 0):

[`ndgrid`](http://www.mathworks.es/es/help/matlab/ref/ndgrid.html) can do this for you, easily and with great generality:

- The number of digits can be made arbitrary using a [comma-separated list](http://www.mathworks.es/es/help/matlab/matlab_prog/comma-separated-lists.html) (generated from a cell array) as the output of `ndgrid`.
- The number of digit values is arbitrary.

The code is as follows:

```
n = 3; %// number of digits. Arbitrary
vals = [0 .5 1]; %// digits values. Arbitrary values and size

counter = cell(1,n); %// initiallize to appropriate size
[counter{:}] = ndgrid(vals); %// generate digits
counter = fliplr(counter); %// least-significant to the left
counter = cellfun(@(v) v(:), counter, 'uni', 0); %// convert arrays to vectors
counter = [counter{:}];  %// convert list of vectors to matrix
```

Examples:

1. With `n=3`, `vals = [0 .5 1]`:

   ```
            0         0         0
            0         0    0.5000
            0         0    1.0000
            0    0.5000         0
            0    0.5000    0.5000
            0    0.5000    1.0000
            0    1.0000         0
            0    1.0000    0.5000
            0    1.0000    1.0000
       0.5000         0         0
                            [...]
   ```
2. With `n=2`, `vals = [0 .25 .75 1]`:

   ```
        0         0
        0    0.2500
        0    0.7500
        0    1.0000
   0.2500         0
   0.2500    0.2500
              [...]
   ```

Comment: With `ndgrid`, you generate `N` matrices of size `3^N`, which would cost too much memory when `N = 16`. The question was how to generate the sequences incrementally (but then obviuosly it would take forever ...)

Comment: @BasSwinckels You're right... I got too excited about using `ndgrid` with a comma-separated list of arbitrary size, and I didn't see that requirement